# How to update each textbox value to each row column in gridview, then update the value into database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I had faced some difficulties while coding and seeking for help from everyone.
I had added textbox in gridview and bind the database details in gridview.
The purpose of the textbox is to update the value in a column named "Total Quantity Redeemed".
I had code the following code but the problem occur.
Only the last row textbox value will update for all the column value.
Example,my last row textbox value is '2',the database will update all column of "Total Quantity Redeemed" to 2. This might happen because of my for loop?
Or should I use rowdatabound?
Hopefully someone could clear my doubt, thank you.

MY HTML CODE(Gridview)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" HeaderStyle-Height="30px" style="border-left-color: black; border-bottom-color: black; border-top-style: dashed; border-top-color: black; border-right-style: dashed; border-left-style: dashed; background-color: silver; border-right-color: black; border-bottom-style: dashed" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Transaction No" >
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="70px"/>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTransactionNo" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("TransactionNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="PaymentDateTime" HeaderText="Payment Date Time">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemCode" HeaderText="Ticket Code"  >
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="65px"/>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="programdesc" HeaderText="Program Description">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="95px" />
            </asp:BoundField>

            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Quantity Available">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="70px"/>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAvailable" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Total Quantity Redeemed">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="70px"/>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRedeemedQty" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("RedeemedQuantity") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity to Redeem" ShowHeader="False">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="95px" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRedeem" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:CompareValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="CompareValidator1" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Integer!" ControlToValidate="txtRedeem"></asp:CompareValidator>
                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Key In Value!" ControlToValidate="txtRedeem"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridheader" Height="30px" BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridaltrow" BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <RowStyle CssClass="gridrow" BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

My behind code

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim sqlQuery As String
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=gsc-volvo-Hp;Database=GET_PANORAMA;Trusted_Connection=True;")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    'Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If (Page.IsPostBack = False) Then

            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            'Dim dr As SqlDataReader
            Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()

            conn.Open()
            sqlQuery = "SELECT webtpay_trn.*,PaymentDateTime from webtrcp_trn inner join webtpay_trn on (webtrcp_trn.TransactionNo = webtpay_trn.TransactionNo)"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn)
            da.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn)

            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            GridView1.DataBind()
            conn.Close()
        End If

    End Sub




Private Sub CheckQty()
Dim row As GridViewRow
Dim total As Integer
lblMessage.Text = ""

For Each row In GridView1.Rows
    Dim lblAvailable As Integer
    Dim lblRedeemedQty As Integer
    Dim amtRedeem As Integer
    Dim transNo As String

    ' write ur DB process code here

    row.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Empty
    lblMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Empty

    Try
        lblAvailable = CType(row.FindControl("lblAvailable"), Label).Text
        amtRedeem = CType(row.FindControl("txtRedeem"), TextBox).Text
        lblRedeemedQty = CType(row.FindControl("lblRedeemedQty"), Label).Text
        transNo = CType(row.FindControl("lblTransactionNo"), Label).Text

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        lblError.Text = "** Error Occur In Quantity Redeem.Default=0 **"
    End Try

    total = total + amtRedeem

    If (amtRedeem > lblAvailable) Or amtRedeem < 0 Then
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        lblMessage.Text = "** Quantity Error or Insufficient. Please Check Your Redeem Quantity **"

        row.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        row.Focus()

        Exit For

    ElseIf total = 0 Then
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        lblMessage.Text = "** No Amount Entered. Please Enter Some Value **"

    Else


    sqlQuery = sqlQuery + "Update WebTpay_Trn set RedeemedQuantity =RedeemedQuantity + '" & amtRedeem & "' "
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " WHERE webtpay_trn.TransactionNo = '" & transNo & "'  "
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn)

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()

        'lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        lblMessage.Text = " Total Redeem =  " + total.ToString + " Tickets "
        'Response.Redirect("showTicketRedeem.aspx")
    End If

Next
End Sub


    Protected Sub btnRedeem_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRedeem.Click

        CheckQty()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/du5iev50p/
Hope the screenshot explain more on the issue

Comment: Show html of GridView

Comment: html updated on post

Comment: where in the code behind are you assigning the value of the textbox txtRedeem to lblRedeemedQty?

Comment: I think I don't have those code, may I know how to code it?
I didn't have it because I update the lblRedeemedQty through query

And I did realise a problem, using update query,it will only update the value I keyed in textbox. Example,I key in 3 on last row,although my Redeemed Quantity have 1,suppose it should sum up and become 4,but it result in overwriting and become 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i guess problem is that you have declared the variables `amtRedeem and total outside the loop` so these variables hold the `old values` in next iteration. So you need to declare these `inside the loop`. I am not sure about the variable `total` but `amtRedeem` must be inside loop.

```
For Each row In GridView1.Rows
Dim amtRedeem As Integer
Dim total As Integer
//Rest of your code will remain same.
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,but problem still occur.
all column still update same value when either one textbox is entered a value

Comment: You are adding an integer with a label not with label's text property change this `lblRedeemedQty = lblRedeemedQty + amtRedeem` to `lblRedeemedQty.Text = lblRedeemedQty.Text + amtRedeem;` You may need to parse value of label in `int`.

Comment: Also when updating in DB you need to get value from this label `set RedeemedQuantity = '" & lblRedeemedQty.Text &`

Comment: when I edited to lblRedeemedQty.Text,it shows: 'Text' is not a member of 'integer'. I had made some changes in sqlQuery

Comment: Have you declared variable `lblRedeemedQty` in code behind ? If yes than you need to put this inside loop as well and if it is an int variable than you don't need `.Text`.

Comment: yes,i declared it as Integer and put inside my for loop,but still occurring the error

Comment: Have you deleted old data and checked it again ? Because old data will still persist and may cause problems.

Comment: old data?do u mean by database value?i did clear the column to 0 when I found out the problem happen

Comment: Now make it 0 again and check;

Comment: it still happening...Did my sqlQuery made some mistake? I saw on internet there is unnecessary to use "FROM" when updating the query

Comment: WHERE (webtrcp_trn.TransactionNo = webtpay_trn.TransactionNo)

my RedeemQuantity is in webtpay_trn table,so I need change it to WHERE (TransactionNo = webtpay_trn.TransactionNo) ?

Comment: Debug and check what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Think it may be the SQL update statement

```
 UPDATE WebTpay_Trn set RedeemedQuantity = '" & amtRedeem & "' 
 FROM webtrcp_trn INNER JOIN webtpay_trn ON 
 (webtrcp_trn.TransactionNo = webtpay_trn.TransactionNo)
```

There is no WHERE statement, so every RedeemedQuantity field is being updated with the value of current row's txtRedeem textbox.

Add in an item template to hold each row's TransactionNo like you have done for RedeemedQuantity

```
 <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="TransactionNo">
            <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblTransactionNo" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("TransactionNo") %>'>
             </asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
```

Add a variable to hold that row's Transaction No (for example using a label called lblTransactionNo)

```
Dim transactionNo as string = lblTransactionNo.Text
```

You need to add a WHERE statement that references that row's TransactionNo

Something like

```
sqlQuery = String.Format("UPDATE WebTpay_Trn set RedeemedQuantity = {0} 
WHERE webtrcp_trn.TransactionNo = {1}", amtRedeem, transactionNo)
```

Comment: For updating, I don't think you need the inner join, as you are only interested in updating RedeemedQuantity where the TransactionNo is the same as the TransactionNo for the gridview row.

Comment: FROM webtrcp_trn WHERE (webtrcp_trn.TransactionNo = webtpay_trn.TransactionNo)

I had made necessary changes in sqlQuery but still have the problem

Comment: how could I get boundfield value?

Comment: change the boundfield to a templatefield, updated answer above

Comment: it shows variable used before I can assign value,i will update the code again

Comment: have you added in the item template for TransactionNo?

Comment: yes,i had add in but error still occur
Dim transNo As String
transNo = CType(row.FindControl("lblTransactionNo"), Label).Text

Comment: What happens when you ignore the warning and run the code?

Comment: To remove any string format issues I have changed the sql query to use string.format

Comment: it show an error/warning : Name 'lblTransactionNo' is not declared.
mayb the way that hold the TransactionNo is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is the solution or not,but my value could get and insert each textbox to each particular row without problem, thanks for the help from Peter Campbell and Mairaj Ahmad.

hold my transactionNo as following:
Dim lblTransactionNo As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("lblTransactionNo"), Label)

```
sqlQuery = "Update WebTpay_Trn set RedeemedQuantity = RedeemedQuantity + '" & amtRedeem & "' "
                    sqlQuery = sqlQuery + " WHERE TransactionNo = '" & lblTransactionNo.Text & "' "
                    'sqlQuery = String.Format("UPDATE WebTpay_Trn set RedeemededQuantity = {0} WHERE webtPay_trn.TransactionNo = {1}", amtRedeem, lbltransactionNo)

                    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn)

                    conn.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    conn.Close()
```